Second NonCPS function fails
I have a pipline using two similar functions, both annotated as NonCPS. First function works, but second always fail with NotSerializable exception.
@NonCPS
def findRuntimeKitVersion (xml) {
    def xmlparsed = new XmlSlurper(false,true).parseText(xml)
                    
    echo xmlparsed.attributes()['count'] + " files found"

    def versionFound

    xmlparsed.file.findAll { def fileNode ->
        result = fileNode.@name.text() =~ /.*-(.*)-RuntimeKit.*/
    }.each { runtimeFileNode ->
        versionFound = result[0][1]
        echo "Found version " + versionFound
    }
    if (!versionFound) {
        error ("Product version was not found")
    } else {
        return versionFound
    }
}

@NonCPS
def findRuntimeKitPath (xml) {
    def xmlparsed = new XmlSlurper(false,true).parseText(xml)
                    
    echo xmlparsed.attributes()['count'] + " files found"

    def href

    xmlparsed.file.findAll { def fileNode ->
        fileNode.@name.text() =~ /.*-(.*)-RuntimeKit.*/
    }.each { runtimeFileNode ->
        href = runtimeFileNode.content.@href.text()
    }
    if (!href) {
        error ("Product path was not found")
    } else {
        return href
    }
}

They are called one after another:
version = findRuntimeKitVersion(xml)

echo "Choosing version " + version

def href = findRuntimeKitPath(xml)

No matter what I do with findRuntimeKitPath function (even copied code from first one) it always gives NotSerializable exception, but first one always work.
What is the problem here?
UPD: Exact error is always against non-serializable Matcher
an exception which occurred:
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.withscript.WithScriptScript.script
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.AnyScript@4cfc55bb
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@23c5cb09
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@137d8335
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@2b0a0f6
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@2b0a0f6
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 0dc4d637-2256-4b3f-afc5-35e9be4c4cfd
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:278)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(LinkedHashMap.java:334)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1497)

I did some more tests and now i am very confused. It seems that it is the first function is raising exception, but it does after all the code work and return. I left only one function and one call for it, removed everything else, exception still happens.

what is the full error message? what exactly is not serializable? try to return string from every method  - use .toString().

Added output and some more information which confuse me even more.

I believe the error is correct that the regex matcher without an assignment is not serializable. The weird part is that it is annotated @NonCPS so that should not matter.

result = fileNode.@name.text() =~ ... this line provokes the error.  you are assigning value  (Matcher) into an undeclared (global) variable. all global variables must be serializable.

Thank you! I was sure first block was working and not set def there to make it local. Thanks!
